# Dictionary for the language of javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a dictionary for the language of javascript?

Eg if I want to lookup what "catch" is/means/does in javascript.

And also to get a good overview of ALL the "words" of the language to see what "words" you have missed.

Comment: With dictionary I mean a list of ALL the words you can ever imagine writing in javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest the [JavaScript Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference) at the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript).

Comment: Not what I menth by "dictionary" with all "words". But will look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

It lists all of the currently key words, as well as those reserved for future use along with links explaining what they mean and how they are used.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at JavaScript: The Good Parts, it is a good read.

Comment: I would recommend NOT referring to w3schools, at least until you have read http://w3fools.com/

Comment: http://w3fools.com Please don't link to W3 Schools - it's incorrect in many places and the MDN is a lot better.

Comment: Did not know that. Removed the link. Thanks for the hint!